# how to fetch the other values in the database equivalent to the selected dropdown item

Tags: php

This is my working code that fetches the data of the id_no in the database. Now, what I want is when I selected a specific id_no the name of the person owning that id_no will automatically be printed. :

```
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT id_no from employee ORDER BY id_no asc";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

        <select name='id_no'>
           <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
           <option value="id_no" > <?php echo($row['id_no']); ?> </option> 
           <?php }  ?> 
        </select>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: i think you can do that via javascript.

Comment: http://www.designing4u.de/2008/05/jquery-drop-down-loading-content-according-to-option/

Comment: it didn't work ugggh

Comment: I need to catch it from database tho.

Answer (score 1):

this code will display the selected value. try this

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id_no from employee ORDER BY id_no asc";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

    <select name='id_no' onchange="changeSelect(this.value)">
       <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo($row['id_no']); ?>" > 
           <?php echo($row['id_no']); ?> 
       </option> 
       <?php }  ?> 
    </select>

    <div id="demo"></div>
    <input type="text" id="text-input" />


    <script>
    function changeSelect(value)
    {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
       document.getElementById("text-input").value = value;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: ah, additional question, how will i print the name inside a text box? your help will be much appreciated:)

Comment: in what part do you want to that process?